# How to simply deactivate a button?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I've connected the button with my ViewController.swift.

```
@IBAction func buttPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
   //DO THINGS
}
```

When it's job get done, how to simply deactivate it? The other answers suggested that:

```
button.enabled = false
```

But I can't figured out how to use it, so how to handle this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In which way does `button.enabled = false` not accomplish your goal? Can you be a little more descriptive of the issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: What do you mean you can't figure out how to handle it?

Comment: Saying "I can't figure out how to use it" is profoundly un-helpful. Why not? What happens? Be descriptive. Does it give you a compile-time error? What is the exact error? Does it give you runtime error? What is the exact error? Does it compile and run without error but it doesn't do what you want? Learn to ask questions that people can answer the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should make an `IBOutlet` too. At the moment you've only a function which will be executed, if you touch on it.

So connect the Button to your UIViewcontroller and choose `Outlet`:

[image]

then in one of your methods you can set the `enabled` property to `false`:

```
yourButton.enabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast the sender of the message to an `UIButton` and then set the enable property as other suggests, something like this:

```
@IBAction func buttPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    //DO THINGS
    if let button = sender as? UIButton {
        button.enabled = false
    }
}
```

the optional casting is not necessary if you can guarantee that the sender will always be an `UIButton`, but it is safer to use. You can also change the data type of the sender, like this:

```
@IBAction func buttPressed(button: UIButton) {
    //DO THINGS
    button.enabled = false
}
```

Comment: Good job reading the OPs mind and figuring out what was wrong without him/her telling us. Nice complete answer as well. (Voted)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a Referencing Outlet for your button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
```